# Matplotlib: plot offset curves, each with corresponding y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm a newbye getting his hands on Matplotlib for the first time.
I'd like to plot some (four) different set of data in the same plot and I need to offset them because otherwise they would overlap.

This is what I need to obtain: http://s4.postimg.org/skaclr06l/example.jpg

Now, it would be simple to add a constant to the different data sets to offset them, but I need every plot to have a corresponding ordinate axis starting from 0 as you can see from the example I posted. 
I found a solution which gets quite close to it on matplotlib website:

```
# Three subplots sharing both x/y axes
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_title('Sharing both axes')
ax2.scatter(x, y)
ax3.scatter(x, 2 * y ** 2 - 1, color='r')
# Fine-tune figure; make subplots close to each other and hide x ticks for
# all but bottom plot.
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-1]], visible=False)
```

The problem is that in this way I get separate plots, whereas I'd like them to overlap partly, as is usually done, for example, with absorption spectra (see an example here http://nte-serveur.univ-lyon1.fr/spectroscopie/raman/Image42.gif)

Could you help me?

Comment: I find that linked example incredibly misleading from a science PoV.  I would just offset the curves on the same axes.

Comment: Not to be a party pooper, if that's the agreed form that's ok. But I've got to say that graphs is dogonUgly. I'm also fairly certain you're not going to get far in mpl with this (even with twinx and twiny). May I suggest [AxesGrid](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html)?

Answer (score 0):

habe you tries to plot each curve separately and in the end use one plt.show()?

This will plot the curves on the same figure, but you'd have to provide an offset for the y values.